# Is the memory usage of typical software exaggerated?

Tags: linux, memory, shared-library, mmap, gnome-system-monitor

Suppose multiple processes are using the same shared library (such as Gtk). Presumably, they `mmap` the library file, and physically, the RAM is shared?

However, the size of the library gets added to each process's memory size, as shown in the system monitor, leading to exaggerated numbers. Is this accurate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual memory accounting separates shared memory from private memory, but some tools aggregate these when displaying process memory use.  Also, cgroups will charge the process for that memory use, so if you have a max memory limit in cgroups, this counts.

This doesn't exaggerate the process's memory use -- it really is using that memory.  But if you look at total memory use of a group of processes and only look at the combined totals, the results will be inflated over real use.  There's no simple way to tell how many times a shared library is being reused without digging through the libraries each process is using, although it should be accounted for correctly in cgroups.

So if you wanted to know the true memory use of a group of processes, and felt justified in adding them all to the same memory cgroup, this should give you a correct answer.